My navy blue prints purple. Looking for a different recipe but same navy effect. Is there a tool that can help find an equivalent?
The blue we have in our logo tends to print very purplish (c100, m86, y29, k23). Is there a tool we can use to find a similar cmyk recipe that offers a navy colour in a similar range but possibly has more black and yellow than magenta? So it offers the same "visual" tone despite the slight difference in warmth or coolness of the colour. The only way I can explain it is kinda like Amazon's "other customers liked this" but for colours. My Pantone chart offers too different a swatch difference when I check. I don't know how else to explain it.

There is no way we can know what your color looks like and theres no recepie we can give you. CMYK colors are not universal, they are device dependent signals. So each device will make a different color with those CMYK values. So you need to pair the CMYK value with some info about what your device is like, either by supplying your own profile or by specifying standard profile. This way any of my devices can be adjusted so it shows what you intended. This is why you use a calibrated screen so that you can search for the color on screen.
